# Automatically replace string with image location in angular

Tags: angular, dom, ionic-framework

I am building a frame data app for a fighting game in angular/ionic which I am still not that familiar with.
There is going to be a spreadsheet for every character which shows the properties of all of their moves.

[Example Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scMmI.png)

For most columns plain text is fine, but for the "command" and "level" column, I would like the program to interpret the strings that I set beforehand and change them to an **image location**.

A single container consist of **multiple commands** that need to be changed. The number will reference a direction on the num-pad while the A,B,K and G will be a reference to horizontal, vertical, kick or guard. 
For example: The string "6 A" should result in loading a picture of an arrow to the right -> and an image of the A button.

The values to put into the spreadsheet are loaded from the corresponding .ts file. (example for horizontal moves)

```
export class Sc6mitsurugiPage {

  horMoves = [
    {move : "Twin Splinters", command: "A", level: "H", dmg: "12", grd: "-8", hit: "2", ch: "2", notes: ""},
    {move : "Twin Splinters (C)", command: "A A", level: "H", dmg: "28", grd: "-6", hit: "6", ch: "6", notes: ""},
    {move : "Reaver", command: "6 A", level: "H", dmg: "18", grd: "-2", hit: "8", ch: "8", notes: ""},
    {move : "Splitting Gold", command: "3 A", level: "M", dmg: "22", grd: "-6", hit: "4", ch: "STN", notes: ""},
    {move : "Knee Slice", command: "2 A", level: "SL", dmg: "12", grd: "-6", hit: "8", ch: "8", notes: ""},
    {move : "Shin Slicer", command: "1 A", level: "L", dmg: "38", grd: "-16", hit: "KND", ch: "KND", notes: ""},
    {move : "Shin Slicer Feint", command: "1 A~B", level: "M", dmg: "42", grd: "12", hit: "SLNC", ch: "SLNC", notes: ""},
    {move : "Dawn Breath", command: "4 A", level: "M", dmg: "28", grd: "-4", hit: "4", ch: "4", notes: ""},
    {move : "Dawn Breath ~Mist", command: "4 A 6", level: "H, SS", dmg: "28", grd: "-2", hit: "6", ch: "6", notes: ""},
    {move : "Knee Slice", command: "FC A", level: "SL", dmg: "12", grd: "-6", hit: "8", ch: "8", notes: ""},
    {move : "Silent Slash", command: "WR A", level: "M", dmg: "28", grd: "-7", hit: "5", ch: "5", notes: ""},
    {move : "Field Reave", command: "7 A", level: "H", dmg: "22", grd: "-3", hit: "7", ch: "7", notes: ""},
    {move : "Field Reave", command: "8 A", level: "H", dmg: "24", grd: "-3", hit: "7", ch: "7", notes: ""},
    {move : "Field Reave", command: "9 A", level: "H", dmg: "26", grd: "-3", hit: "7", ch: "7", notes: ""},
    {move : "Reverse Slice", command: "BT A", level: "H", dmg: "14", grd: "-6", hit: "6", ch: "7", notes: ""},
    {move : "Hidden Slice", command: "BT 2 A", level: "SL", dmg: "14", grd: "-6", hit: "8", ch: "8", notes: ""}
  ];
```

Is it possible to do this while only having a **single string** as the value for command/level or would it make more sense to have an **array of strings** with all of them just being a single character?
If the latter is true, how would I have to change the data structure?

This is the relevant part of my current HTML file:

```
<ion-row nowrap *ngFor="let horMove of horMoves">
  <ion-col class="sheetColumn wideCol">
    <div>{{horMove.move}}</div>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col class="sheetColumn wideCol">
      <div>{{horMove.command}}</div>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col class="sheetColumn narrowCol">
      <div>{{horMove.level}}</div>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col class="sheetColumn narrowCol">
      <div>{{horMove.dmg}}</div>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col class="sheetColumn narrowCol">
      <div>{{horMove.grd}}</div>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col class="sheetColumn narrowCol">
      <div>{{horMove.hit}}</div>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col class="sheetColumn narrowCol">
      <div>{{horMove.ch}}</div>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col class="sheetColumn wideCol">
      <div><img class="inputImg" src="assets/imgs/input/a.png"><img class="inputImg" src="assets/imgs/input/b.png"><img class="inputImg" src="assets/imgs/input/k.png"><img class="inputImg" src="assets/imgs/input/g.png"></div>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

How would I need to go about having the **relevant pictures show up** on the spreadsheet instead of just plain text?

Comment: could you post your mapping between char to image path ?

Comment: @yanis-git mapping as in file location and naming convention?
All the images are in "assets/imgs/input/" and are named A, B, G or numbers from 1-9.
I think I've come a bit closer to the solution by giving the div that holds the string for command a specific class that I can then find in the Dom. That way I managed to exchange parts of the string with the desired picture. However I'm still not quite sure how to completely implement this character by character.

Comment: sorry i means, command A is this picture, command WR A is this picture... i am worry to not understand what you try to acheive so far

Comment: @yanis-git Sorry I wasn't clear enough and thanks for the support. 
for example, the string "6A" should fetch 2 pictures. The picture "assets/imgs/input/6.png" and also the picture "assets/imgs/input/A.png" and display them in the "command" column. 
WR stands for "While rising" and BT stands for "Back turned", but it seems like I have to come up with my own naming convention and keep it to one character.
I've come pretty close to the solution now. I will post it later to inquire if it can be improved upon.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution for my original problem, however I am pretty sure that there must be better ways to go about this and I'd be happy if someone would post another answer, stating those.

I changed all the commands in command that are longer than one letter to a single letter:
FC (full Crouch) => C, WR (While Rising) => W, BT (Back Turn) => T etc. in my array.

```
  horMoves = [
    {move : "Twin Splinters", command: "A", level: "H", dmg: "12", grd: "-8", hit: "2", ch: "2", notes: ""},
    {move : "Twin Splinters (C)", command: "AA", level: "H", dmg: "28", grd: "-6", hit: "6", ch: "6", notes: ""},
    {move : "Reaver", command: "6A", level: "H", dmg: "18", grd: "-2", hit: "8", ch: "8", notes: ""},
    {move : "Splitting Gold", command: "3A", level: "M", dmg: "22", grd: "-6", hit: "4", ch: "STN", notes: ""},
    {move : "Knee Slice", command: "2A", level: "SL", dmg: "12", grd: "-6", hit: "8", ch: "8", notes: ""},
    {move : "Shin Slicer", command: "1A", level: "L", dmg: "38", grd: "-16", hit: "KND", ch: "KND", notes: ""},
    {move : "Shin Slicer Feint", command: "1M", level: "M", dmg: "42", grd: "12", hit: "SLNC", ch: "SLNC", notes: ""},
    {move : "Dawn Breath", command: "4A", level: "M", dmg: "28", grd: "-4", hit: "4", ch: "4", notes: ""},
    {move : "Dawn Breath ~Mist", command: "4A6", level: "H, SS", dmg: "28", grd: "-2", hit: "6", ch: "6", notes: ""},
    {move : "Knee Slice", command: "CA", level: "SL", dmg: "12", grd: "-6", hit: "8", ch: "8", notes: ""},
    {move : "Silent Slash", command: "WA", level: "M", dmg: "28", grd: "-7", hit: "5", ch: "5", notes: ""},
    {move : "Field Reave", command: "7A", level: "H", dmg: "22", grd: "-3", hit: "7", ch: "7", notes: ""},
    {move : "Field Reave", command: "8A", level: "H", dmg: "24", grd: "-3", hit: "7", ch: "7", notes: ""},
    {move : "Field Reave", command: "9A", level: "H", dmg: "26", grd: "-3", hit: "7", ch: "7", notes: ""},
    {move : "Reverse Slice", command: "TA", level: "H", dmg: "14", grd: "-6", hit: "6", ch: "7", notes: ""},
    {move : "Hidden Slice", command: "T2A", level: "SL", dmg: "14", grd: "-6", hit: "8", ch: "8", notes: ""}
  ];
```

I then gave the div that holds the command a special class, so it can be found in the DOM.

```
<ion-col class="sheetColumn wideCol">
  <div class="command">{{horMove.command}}</div>
</ion-col>
```

After that I went into the corresponding .ts file and started manipulating the DOM.
This code fetches all the nodes that have the "command" class and I can then use that list to iterate over every single letter and create a new  element that will then be appended to the right place in the DOM.

```
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    let comArr = document.getElementsByClassName("command"); // Fetches a nodelist with all command cells
    for(let i = 0; i < comArr.length; i++){
      let elString = document.getElementsByClassName("command")[i].innerHTML; // Fetches string for this iteration of the loop
      document.getElementsByClassName("command")[i].innerHTML = ""; // Clears raw text from column
      for(let j = 0; j < elString.length; j++){
        let newImg = document.createElement("img"); // creates new <img>
        newImg.setAttribute("class", "inputImg"); //  sets class for <img>
        let alphaNum = elString[j];

        switch(alphaNum){

          //Diretions
          case "1": //Lower Left
            newImg.setAttribute("src", "assets/imgs/input/1.png");
            break;

          case "2": //Bottom
            newImg.setAttribute("src", "assets/imgs/input/2.png");
            break;

          case "3": //Lower Right
            newImg.setAttribute("src", "assets/imgs/input/3.png");
            break;

          case "4": //Left
            newImg.setAttribute("src", "assets/imgs/input/4.png");
            break;

          case "6": //Right
            newImg.setAttribute("src", "assets/imgs/input/6.png");
            break;

          case "7": //Upper Left
            newImg.setAttribute("src", "assets/imgs/input/7.png");
            break;

          case "8": //Top
            newImg.setAttribute("src", "assets/imgs/input/8.png");
            break;

          case "9": //Upper Right
            newImg.setAttribute("src", "assets/imgs/input/9.png");
            break;

          //Standard Buttons
          case "A": //Horizontal
            newImg.setAttribute("src", "assets/imgs/input/A.png");
            break;

          case "B": //Vertical
            newImg.setAttribute("src", "assets/imgs/input/B.png");
            break;

          case "K": //Kick
            newImg.setAttribute("src", "assets/imgs/input/K.png");
            break;

          case "G": //Guard
            newImg.setAttribute("src", "assets/imgs/input/G.png");
            break;

          //Multi Button
          case "M": // A~B Horizontal ~ Vertical
            newImg.setAttribute("src", "assets/imgs/input/M.png");
            newImg.setAttribute("class", "inputImgWide");
            break;

          case "N": // B~A Vertical ~ Horizontal
            newImg.setAttribute("src", "assets/imgs/input/N.png");
            newImg.setAttribute("class", "inputImgWide");
            break;

          case "O": // K~A Kick ~ Horizontal
            newImg.setAttribute("src", "assets/imgs/input/O.png");
            newImg.setAttribute("class", "inputImgWide");
            break;

          case "P": // K~B Kick ~ Vertical
            newImg.setAttribute("src", "assets/imgs/input/P.png");
            newImg.setAttribute("class", "inputImgWide");
            break;

          // States (Not complete yet)
          case "C": // Full Crouch
            break;

          case "T": // Back Turn
            break;

          case "R": // Run
            break;

          case "W": // While Rising
            break;
        }
        document.getElementsByClassName("command")[i].appendChild(newImg) // appends <img> child to corresponding cell
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So far it's working fine, but I'm worried that I will start running out of possible characters and everything will start to become chaotic once I add all the special stances of every character to the switch statement.

[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FF6Q9.png)